# Forcibly unbind a port in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, svn, port

So, I'm trying to set up a subversion server on Windows 7, and am having a problem with bound ports. I searched around a bit, and found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/417636/what-is-binding-this-port) about how to handle this, but I'm having a problem implementing the solution there.

The problem is, port 443 is being bound by `System`. Where normally I would follow that answer, there is no process to kill. Here is the relevant `netstat -anb` output:

```
 TCP    192.168.1.2:52086      74.125.224.162:443     ESTABLISHED
[System]
 TCP    192.168.1.2:52093      74.125.224.192:443     ESTABLISHED
[System]
```

Is there any way to forcibly unbind a port without a full reboot? Also, what could be causing this bind?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I had the same problem, so I'm now including the header names in my grep/filter.

```
netstat -a -o -n -b | Select-String "5436|543\d+|Connections|Address"
 
Write-Warning "Fill in the port of your choice"
netstat -a -o -n -b | Select-String "<YourPortHere>|Connections|Address"
```

Answer (score -2):

Goddam!!!

1. `74.125.224.192:443` is **foreign** address, **READ COLUMN TITLES** in netstat output!!! (*you*, as client, connect to *external https* resource)
2. Apache-based repo-server can be used on local 80 and **any** (443 too) https ports
3. Svnserve-based server doesn't require free 443 port also

Comment: Well that's a little aggressive. _Something_ is binding port 443, and that's what I got in response from `netstat`, so excuse me for being a little confused.